# Unable to retrieve the parameter from the url using $routeParams

Tags: angularjs

i am unable to retrieve the param values from the url in the current page using $routeParams.

This is the route configuration i have.

routing .js

```
   `when('/viewJobDetails/:qid/:jid',{
    templateUrl:'viewJobDetails.jsp',
    controller :'viewJobDetailsCtrl'
   }).`


   fmApp.controller('viewJobDetailsCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$routeParams','$window',function($scope,$resource,$window,$routeParams){
   console.log("------viewJobDeatailsCtrl-------");
   /*$scope.jobDetails={};
   $scope.jobDetails.qid=$routeParams.qid;
   $scope.jobDetails.jid=$routeParams.jid;*/

   $scope.qid=$routeParams.qid;
   $scope.jid=$routeParams.jid;
  console.log("qid and jid :"+$scope.qid+" "+$scope.jid);


  }])
```

And this is how iam sending the url request along the parameters

```
  <td><a href="#/viewJobDetails/{{q.qid}}/{{q.jid}}" >{{q.jid}}</a></td>
```

At the end of this , both values in the  console are "undefined"
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will completely resolve your issue, but you should use ng-href instead of href since you are using interpolation in the URL.

Comment: yes indeed using "ng-href"  will solve the issue and i have also mentioned this in the above comments to Sergiu Paraschiv..
  Using Plain "href" instead "ng-href" will make the link point to the wrong url. if at all the user clicks on the link before the anular gets a chance to replace it with the appropriate code.

@bliles ,Thank you for your concern to answer

Answer (score 0):

`'$scope','$resource','$routeParams','$window'` => `$scope,$resource,$window,$routeParams`

Order does matter!
Switch `$window` and `$routeParams` to the same position.

http://jsfiddle.net/4uytmqxv/

Comment: it has no effect even after the switch,.
  please point out any other issues u see..
  is there any issues related the scope? i am setting the url request in different page and trying to retrieve the params  in different page..?

Comment: Works for me. Did you include `angular-route.js` and add `ngRoute` as a dependency to your module?

Comment: Then you'll need to show us the rest of your code and check your error console.

Comment: rest of the code as in?

      <td><a href="#/viewJobDetails/{{q.qid}}/{{q.jid}}" >{{q.jid}}</a></td>
the above request is made in the "home.jsp" within  "homeCtrl"
and im trying to retrieve the params inside the "viewJobDetailsCtrl"
might this be the problem?

Comment: No, it is not a problem. The "above request" you are talking about has nothing to do with AngularJS. You could write that URL directly in your browser and the same thing would happen. Something else is obviously wrong in your code, the one you are not showing us. Again, I've posted a _working_ example. You should reduce your code to something similar and update your question.

Comment: using "ngHref" solved the issue...
 The problem was that i was using the markup like "{{qid}}" and this will make the link go the wrong url if "href" plain is used., if user clicks on it before the angular gets a chance to replace it with the corresponding code..   [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)
Thank you for your concern   Sergiu Paraschiv